# Is there a way to migrate svn without using svnadmin dump?

Tags: windows, linux, svn, migration, repository

My linux box has unfortunately died. I can access the raw SVN repositories from a backup and I need to revive them on my Windows box (at least for the timebeing). Is there a way of migrating/importing these repositories, given that I can't run "svnadmin dump" on the linux box?

Comment: Backup and restore questions belong on serverfault.  That said, it will probably work to move the files to Windows.  Just make sure you use the exact same version of svn (and then dump it, reload it the latest version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest booting from a Linux live CD of the same distribution as your Linux server, or create a virtual machine with VMWare Player or VirtualBox and mount the filesystem, then you can do an svnadmin dump from there.

Comment: Great suggestion, thanks. And a good bit of lateral thinking. I'm back up and running with all my repositories intact.

Answer (score 1):

As it's no longer in use (no commits or checkouts), try copying the whole repo to your Windows box.